# Lua: Correct setup of additional http.request headers

Tags: lua, http-headers

I try to form a `http.request` with additional headers.
(Ultimate goal: provide an access token, but the problem seems to be the way of adding headers).

The "normal" request works, but in the moment I try to add a header, I fail, but unfortunately without any error message. The request seems to segfault.
I have the same effect no matter what kind of header I add. Thus, I believe that I misunderstand the API.

```
local http = require "http.request"

local req = http.new_from_uri(uri)
-- I succeed, if I comment out the following line
req.headers:upsert("Accept", "application/vnd.github+json")
local headers, stream = assert(req:go())
```

I also fail, if I use `req.headers:append` instead of `req.headers:upsert`.
What am I doing wrong?